# How do you find the expectation of process involving Brownian motions at different times?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $W(t)$ be a Brownian motion, and say we want to find $(t_{2}\geq t_{1})$:

$\mathbb{E}[W(t_{1})e^{W(t_{2})}]$

Could we just rewrite this as finding the result to:

$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }\sqrt{t_{1}}xe^{\sqrt{t_{2}}x}f(x)dx$

(where  is the density of a standard normal random variable)?

Comment: No, you need to find the join density $f_{W_{t_1},W_{t_2}}$ of $(W_{t_1},W_{t_2})$. When you found it, then your expectation will be $$\iint_{\mathbb R^2}xe^{y}f_{W_{t_1},W_{t_2}}(x,y)\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that won't work because $W(t_1)$ and $W(t_2)$ are not perfectly correlated.  Instead, you would want to use the independent increments property to write \begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[W(t_1)e^{W(t_2)}] &= \mathbb{E}[W(t_1)e^{W(t_2)-W(t_1)+W(t_1)}] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[W(t_1)e^{W(t_1)}]\mathbb{E}[e^{W(t_2)-W(t_1)}].
\end{align*}
You can evaluate the second expectation as the moment generating function of a $N(0,t_2-t_1)$ random variable.  The first expectation you can evaluate as the integral $\int \sqrt{t_1}xe^{\sqrt{t_1}x}f(x) dx$ where $f$ is the pdf of a $N(0,1)$ random variable.

Comment: Ah I see. I know how to calculate the first expectation, but I am not sure how to go about evaluating the second expectation. What does a moment generating function of a $N(0,t_{2}-t_{1})$ mean?

Comment: It's known that if $X \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, then $\mathbb{E}[e^{tX}] = e^{\frac 12 t^2 \sigma^2}$.